# Where or how can I find BizTalk server's database for attaching them to SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

When I want to debug my project, this error will be shown:

> Deployment cannot initialize the connection to the database "" on server "(LOCAL)". Verify that you have the required security permissions and that communication between Distributed Transaction Coordinator services on the machines involved is not prevented by current DTC security,   firewall or authentication settings. 
>   Parameter name: strDBName

What should I do?

Comment: Fix the connection string?

Comment: but no database is appeared. Plus in biztalk administration I can not connect to databases. Plus I don't know where I can find **BizTalkMgmtDb** .

Comment: Have you asked Google? There are a lot of related web pages to this keyword..

Comment: Do you have BizTalk installed somewhere?  It sounds like it is not configured as usually the BizTalk admin console will show it.  What do you see if you launch BizTalk Server Configuration?

Comment: I found out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this problem we need to access BizTalk related databases. For reaching these databases and installing them we need to configure by following this file:

> **C:\Program Files\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Configuration.exe**

Then we can install BizTalk databases. So we can access them like **BizTalkMgmtDb** . Then we must configure BizTalk Administration. To access databases we should use windows account username and password not SQL SERVER username and password.

Then this error will be disappeared.